# Show that an open subset of a metric space can be expressed as a union of open balls.

Tags: general-topology

Little bit hard for me. I was doing it since last week but it is so complicated.

Comment: If you have been doing it since last week, then you must have some work to show here. Please include what you have tried so far.

Comment: In addition to that: what's your definition of "open subset of a metric space"? Because "a union of balls" might very well be it.

Comment: the union of open balls is it same with it?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Not quite, because although by definition an open set is a union of balls, the converse fact, viz. that a union of balls is an open set, depends on the proposition that an open ball is open - which *sounds* vacuous, but isn't. (This is mere quibbling, I know, because your comment does in fact answer the question perfectly well. I'm going for my pedantry badge.)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Yes, I had forgotten the adjective "open"; when I came back to add it, it was too late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let say $X$ is the open subset. Then $\forall x\in X$ there exists $r(x)>0 $ such that $B_{r(x)}\in X$.Hence, $X$=$\bigcup\limits_{x\in X}B_{r(x)}$.

Comment: first thank you. also I want to show my answers but I dont know how to put  it ffrom my paper. is there any program to do it?

Comment: Google latex. If you found the answer useful, please press " accept the answer " Thank you very much.

Comment: There is a concealed and unnecessary use of the Axiom of Choice here.

Comment: If we consider the level of this prob., I think naive set theory is enough.

Comment: @DaveJoer See [How can I format mathematics here?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @aswe2277 If I'm being overly pedantic (sadly likely), I apologise! I'm no fan of excessive zeal in the use of axiomatic set theory myself, but, just as one can rely on the AoC without formally mentioning it, one can also avoid it without mentioning it. If $B(x, r)$ denotes the open ball with centre $x$ and radius $r$ (by the way, your notation $B_{r(x)}$ unfortunately makes it appear that $B(x, r)$ is specified by a single parameter, $r(x)$), then $X = \bigcup\{B(x, r) : B(x, r) \subseteq X\}$, which I *think* avoids the AoC, although it would be entertaining were someone to out-pedant me. :)

Comment: This teaches me a lot. Thanks you very much for point out such subtle difference. I never consider to such depth before.